# Quartz scheduler working on local machine but not on Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler via spring boot application to schedule a Job on Elastic BeanStalk but its not working . It doesn't throw any error. I have tried the same code on local machine and its working fine.  Can anyone tell me whats causing this issue ,Does elastic Beanstalk have some issue while configuring Elastic BeanStalk through spring boot application.